# Best practice : handling exception in a class

Tags: python

I am interested to know what is the best practice to handle exception in a class.

As far as I read, it is not a good practice to use "print" statements in a class. So programmers return the value and print it outside the class in the main routine. If this is the case how do I validate the exception that is happening in the class?

One way is to use a code something like this,

```
class temp():
    try:
        import os
        return 1
    except:
        return 0
```

This is just an example.

My requirement is something like this, I want to evaluate a statement and I want to catch the exception. Think of this method as a private method, which will be called internally.

E.G. let me try with an example.

```
class test():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def read(self):
        try:
            f = open('file.txt')
            fr = f.readlines()
            return fr
        except Exception as e:
            # not sure should i return e or should i return 0 
            # to say that this function failed.

    def write(self):
        self.handle = self.read()
        if self.handle:
            # do something
        else:
            # return the exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_object = test()
    print test_object.write()
```

Guess I made myself clear on this.

Comment: "not sure should i return e". Returning (instead of raising) an exception is surely... unconventional. Either let the exception go through to the caller or catch it, handle it and maybe re-raise it or another exception (custom one maybe).

Comment: off-topic: you can skip the constructor `__init__` if you do not declare any instance attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you are trying to do but raising an exception to indicate error is the preferred method to indicate that something went wrong with the method.

Sometimes, the best practice is not to handle the exception in class but to handle it when you are calling the method.  Assuming that your `test.read()` is:

```
...
def read(self):
    f = open('file.txt')
    fr = f.readlines()
    return fr
```

You would do:

```
t = test()
try:
    t.read()
except Exception as e:
    # Handle exception here
```

Normally, you handle the exception in your class to perform additional actions such as cleanup.  Instead of returning 0/1/String to "say that function failed", you should raise the same exception.  E.g.:

```
def read(self):
    try:
        f = open('file.txt')
        fr = f.readlines()
        return fr
    except Exception as e:
        if f:
            f.close()
        raise
```

Comment: Interesting, thanks. But is this the best practice ?

Comment: You're raising the same exception, you should just use `raise` without anything afterwards.

Comment: Thanks.. Let me try that.

Comment: @Bala yes, it is the best practice to raise an exception instead of returning 0/1/strings to indicate exception.  Will update the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's usually best to create your own Exceptions and raise those in case something goes wrong. Then the code that makes use of the class can catch those exeptions and do whatever they want to do when this happens.